# keep calling an API until it is updated with latest item (Python)

Tags: python

I'm looking to call an API, and compare the data to my saved data in a CSV. If it has a new data point then I want to update my CSV and return the DataFrame...  The mystery I have is why these two variables appear to be the same, yet the If statement moves to the Else instead of recognizing they are the same, if they are the same it should keep looping until an updated data point appears,(see second_cell == lastItem1 )

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr # https://medium.com/swlh/pandas-datareader-federal-reserve-economic-data-fred-a360c5795013
import datetime

def datagetter():
    i = 1
    while i < 120:
        start = datetime.datetime (2005, 1, 1)              ### Step 1: get data, and print last item
        end = datetime.datetime (2040, 1, 1)
        df = pdr.DataReader('PAYEMS', 'fred', start, end)       ## This is the API
        lastItem1 = df["PAYEMS"].iloc[-1]           # find the last item in the data we have just downloaded
        print ("Latest item from Fred API: " , lastItem1) ### Print the last item
        with open('PAYEMS.csv', 'r') as logs:              # So first we open the most recent CSV file
            data = logs.readlines()
            last_row = data[-1].split(',')                    # split is default on , as CSVs should be.           
            second_cell = last_row[1]                      # "second_cell" is our variable name for the saved datapoint from last month/week/day
            print ("Last Item, in thousands" , second_cell)
            if second_cell == lastItem1:
                print ("CSV " , second_cell, "API ", lastItem1, " downloaded and stored items are the same, will re-loop until a new datapoint")
                print("attempt no.", i)
                i += 1
            else:
                df.to_csv("PAYEMS.csv") 
                print ("returning dataframe")
                # print(df.tail())
                return df          

df = datagetter()
print(df.tail(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

solved my own problem:
my CSV was returning a string, and the API an int... not quite sure why.

So
           `if second_cell == "":                            second_cell = 0 second_cell1 = int(float(second_cell))`